# Python: How to modify for a memory-friendly code

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I have the following code to search all `utf16` encoded `.ini` files and search their contents but RAM usage immediately jumps from 1.3GB to 3.9GB that cause my PC to crash. What certain module is the reason here? How can I do better for this?

```
import os
import chardet
import shutil

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) 
string = r"\v5."

def get_encoding(filename):
    filebyte = open(filename, 'rb')
    detect_encoding = chardet.detect(filebyte.read())        
    file_encoding = detect_encoding['encoding']
    filebyte.close()
    return file_encoding

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path): 
    for file in files: 
        if file.endswith('.ini'):
            filepath = root+'/'+str(file)
            encoding = get_encoding(filepath)
            if encoding == "UTF-16":
                print (filepath)
```

Comment: If you have working code and are looking for improvements, you could post the question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... I agree with @jmd_dk it seems very strange to have `.ini` files that are that big.
Is there some other code that's going on that's not posted?

So, it doesn't appear that your code is memory limiting unless you have an `.ini` file over a 1Gb.

In any case I would recommend using `pathlib` to make things a bit easier for you.

```py
import os
import chardet
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

dir_path = Path(__file__).parent

for item in dir_path.rglob('*.ini'):  # recursive glob
    with item.open('rb') as filebytes:
        detected = chardet.detect(filebytes.read())
        if detected['encoding'] == 'UTF-16':
            print(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be that `filebyte.read()` reads in the entire content of the file, which may be large. Although it does seem weird to have .ini files several GB in size. Try supplying a number to `filebyte.read()`, so that it at max reads this many characters:

```
detect_encoding = chardet.detect(filebyte.read(1000))
```

Comment: Actually, the path is a compilation of built solutions so I have a total of 2300+ `.ini` files

Comment: Unless Python is doing a terrible job of memory management, the number of files should not be an issue. After each call to ` chardet.detect()`, the read in file content is immediately available for garbage collection, as it is not bound to a name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going through in the debugger to find the particular line causing you an issue, but I suspect if your files are very large, you're reading the whole thing into memory. You could check this by evaluating the memory before the call to open(), then during processing, then after close(). You could get around the issue by streaming the file using the io module.

I could also suggest you use the 'with' syntax rather than explicitly calling open() and close(), this ensures you don't forget to close anything. Example:

```
def get_encoding(filename):
   file_encoding = ""

   with open(filename, 'rb') as filebyte:
      detect_encoding = chardet.detect(filebyte.read())
      file_encoding = detect_encoding['encoding']

   return file_encoding
```

Answer (score -1):

I completely agree with jmd_dk but you could also incrementally detect encoding as described here [Incremental Encoding Detection](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), this allows you to read in characters or lines until the detector reaches a specific level of certainty.

This would be helpful if you were concerned about reading too many or too few bytes. You could do something like:

```
if certainty < 0.90: read up to 1000 otherwise break
```